# Force narrowing conversion warning

Tags: c++, c++14, compiler-warnings, implicit-conversion, narrowing

Consider the following code that illustrates some narrowing conversions:

```
template <class T>
class wrapper 
{   
    template <class> friend class wrapper;
    public:
        constexpr wrapper(T value)
        : _data(value)
        {}
        template <class U>
        constexpr wrapper(wrapper<U> other)
        : _data(other._data) 
        {}
        wrapper& operator=(T value)
        {_data = value; return *this;}
        template <class U>
        wrapper& operator=(wrapper<U> other)
        {_data = other._data; return *this;}
    private:
        T _data;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    wrapper<unsigned char> wrapper1 = 5U;
    wrapper<unsigned char> wrapper2{5U};
    wrapper<unsigned char> wrapper3(5U);
    wrapper<unsigned int> wrapper4 = 5U;
    wrapper<unsigned int> wrapper5{5U};
    wrapper<unsigned int> wrapper6(5U);
    wrapper<unsigned char> wrapper7 = wrapper4;  // Narrowing
    wrapper<unsigned char> wrapper8{wrapper5};  // Narrowing
    wrapper<unsigned char> wrapper9(wrapper6);  // Narrowing
    wrapper7 = wrapper4;  // Narrowing
    wrapper8 = wrapper5;  // Narrowing
    wrapper9 = wrapper6;  // Narrowing
    return 0;
}
```

How to change the body of the `wrapper` members, so that it triggers the compiler warning for narrowing conversion? My goal is to make the user aware that something is potentially wrong with their code.

Comment: Where is the narrowing?  You are copying initializing from the same type in 7, 8, and 9.

Comment: Interestingly, there's `-Wnarrowing`, but it doesn't seem to do anything. Making narrowing into errors seems much easier in this case.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks, problem corrected.

Comment: @Vincent No problem.  Would you okay be having an error instead of a warning?

Comment: Yes, that would be even better actually...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can trigger a narrowing conversion warning with uniform initialization syntax:

```
class wrapper 
{   
    template <class> friend class wrapper;
    public:
        constexpr wrapper(T value)
        : _data{value}
        {}
        template <class U>
        constexpr wrapper(wrapper<U> other)
        : _data{other._data} // note the curly brackets here
        {}
        wrapper& operator=(T value)
        {_data = value; return *this;}
        template <class U>
        wrapper& operator=(wrapper<U> other)
        {_data = {other._data}; return *this;} // and here
    private:
        T _data;
};
```

with

```
wrapper<unsigned int> wrapper1 = 5U;
wrapper<unsigned char> wrapper2 = wrapper1;  // Narrowing
wrapper<unsigned char> wrapper3(wrapper1);  // Narrowing
wrapper<unsigned char> wrapper4{wrapper1};  // Narrowing
wrapper2 = wrapper1;  // Narrowing
```

any of the four last lines [will produce a narrowing conversion warning in g++, and compilation errors from the narrowing conversions in clang.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/31182b8264e279dd)

Answer (score 3):

To stop compilation in a narrowing call you can use SFINAE on

```
template <class U>
constexpr wrapper(wrapper<U> other)
: _data(other._data) 
{}
```

And change it to

```
template <class U, typename std::enable_if<sizeof(T) >= sizeof(U)>::type* = nullptr>
constexpr wrapper(wrapper<U> other)
: _data(other._data) 
{}
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a0b0924017a31933)</kbd>

This will stop compilation if the size of the underlying type you are copying from is greater than the underlying type of the object you are initializing.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend a different way. You don't need to muck with your code. When you compile using g++, add the -Wconversion flag.

Comment: Part of the problem is OP's template partially short-circuits the warning.